# Refer to Named Range from Cell Value in For Loop

Tags: vba, excel, range, offset

Good afternoon all,

I'm a bit rusty on my VBA since I have moved onto Programming in other languages, so I was hoping someone would be able to help me.

**What I am Tying to Do**

I have two sheets. One is the form page which users fill out, the other (Sheet1 .... I didn't name it) is basically a data page.

Within Sheet1 I have a table which shows 1 or 0 depending on if a range on the form has a specific selection. Two columns over the cell value states the range that needs an input message. The Macro is supposed to find all of the 1's, lookup the named range found two columns over and insert the named range. Unfortunately I keep getting an Application or Object Defined Error. My code is below:

```
PcentData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentData").Value
    If PcentData > 0 Then
        For Each pCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentSwitch")
            If pCell.Value = 1 Then
                With Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Range(Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2)).Validation 'Error here
                .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
                .InputTitle = "Test"
                .InputMessage = "Test"

                End With
            End If

        Next pCell
    End If
```

EDIT:

I have managed to ensure the code pulls the named range from the correct sheet by defining a string called NamedRange and having it equal the old with statement, pointing to the correct sheet.

```
Dim NamedRange As String
PcentData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentData").Value
    If PcentData > 0 Then
        For Each pCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentSwitch")
            If pCell.Value = 1 Then
                NamedRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2).Value
                MsgBox (Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2).Value)
                With Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Range(NamedRange)
                    If .Validation Then .Validation.Delete
                    .Validation.Add /* Error Here */ Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
                    .InputTitle = "Test"
                    .InputMessage = "Test"
                End With
            End If

        Next pCell
    End If
```

Unfortunately I get the error Object doesnt support this property or method on the If .validation section.

Comment: Try like this: `With Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Range(Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2)).Validation`

Comment: Still get the same error on the same line, although I can see why this could have helped. Would it be better to have this in a module rather than the sheet?

Comment: Can you try like this: `With Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2)).Validation` ?

Comment: I tried this configuration a couple attempts ago. It gets past the With statement itself but errors (1004) on the .Add Type for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Vityata I managed to find a solution to my problem. The issue was the original loop was taking the position of the table i wanted to lookup from the wrong sheet. I stored this in a variable called "NamedRange" and plugged that into the With statement instead of trying to code it directly into the Range().

The next problem was the data validation. It seems it does not like to have the .Validation separate from the With statement, as such if I need to do multiple changed to the cell I will need multiple With statements. Here is the working code:

```
Dim NamedRange As String
PcentData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentData").Value

    If PcentData > 0 Then
        For Each pCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentSwitch")
            If pCell.Value = 1 Then
                NamedRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2).Value
                With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Range(NamedRange).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
                    :=xlBetween
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = "test"
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = "test"
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With
            End If

        Next pCell
    End If
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you may try like this:

```
PcentData = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentData").Value
    If PcentData > 0 Then
        For Each pCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("PcentSwitch")
            If pCell.Value = 1 Then
                With Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 2).validation
                    .delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly
                    .InputTitle = "Test"
                    .InputMessage = "Test"    
                End With
            End If    
        Next pCell
    End If
```

I have removed the `.Range` and I have remove the validation from the current cell.

Comment: This would work but the error message throws up "Object doesnt support this property or method". I put in a MsgBox (Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 1).Value) which comes up blank. So it's not getting the named range from the table... For some reason.

Comment: you can put in the msgbox the following: `Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 1).address`

Comment: Comes up with $V$2 which is correct. Within this cell (in Sheet1) is the named range. My guess is it's trying to pull V2 from the form, which is blank.

Comment: Try with the following: `Sheets("Payment-Deduction Form").Cells(pCell.Row, pCell.Column + 1).parent.name`

Comment: Yep, the parent is the Payment-Deduction Form. I'm trying to think of a way to pull from the sheet where the pCell is located.

Comment: I have changed the code as per my edit which now pulls the name correctly :) Unfortunately it is still having trouble with the validation.

Comment: What trouble? Simply record a macro with validation and implement it.

Comment: Thanks for all your help getting me this far by the way! But the trouble is adding the validation. It doesn't seem to want to work. I get the error "Object doesnt support this property or method" on the .Validation line. It seems to only work if I use the range's absolute value. It's almost time for my shift to end so I will keep thinking about it. After programming in other languages I find VBA to be much more frustrating in terms of its error handling.